# Prove more generally that if $X$ is Hausdorﬀ and I is a set, then the space of constant maps $I \to X$ is closed in $X^I$.

Tags: general-topology

We know of that if $X$ is a Hausdorff Space, then the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x): x \in X\}$  is closed.
Can we generalize it for if $X$ is Hausdorff and then the space of constant maps from $I$ to $X$ is closed in $X^{I}$
if so, how can we start?

Comment: Can $I$ by any index set? You want to show iff (if and only if; equivalence). Please state the hypothesis as exactly as you can so maybe $X$ is Hausdorff iff for any index set $I$ the set of constant functions is closed in $X^I$ (in the product topology ). That would be true.

Comment: that was exactly what I want to state, I is any index set

Answer (score 2):

If $I$ is any index set, WLOG $|I| \ge 2$, and $f:I \to X$ is nonconstant we can find  $i\neq j$ in $I$ such that $f(i) \neq f(j)$. As $X$ is Hausdorff we find disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ around $f(i)$ resp. $f(j)$. Then use the open neighbourhood $p_i^{-1}[U]\cap p_j^{-1}[V]$ of $f$ which misses the set $C$ of constant functions entirely. So no point outside of $C$ is an adherent point of $C$ so the set is closed. For the reverse we only need the case where $I=\{0,1\}$ e.g. and we use that $X^I \simeq X^2$ and the case you already know applies.

Comment: thank you so much appreciated, I will work on it